# SOT23 transistor/FET infromation needed

Tags: transistors, mosfet, identification, fet

I am trying to Reverse Engineering A PCB but I have problem to identify some PCB components(Highlighted components). I don't know whether these are transistors or FETs. As without knowing their actual model number i will not be able to identify their pin configurations.[image]

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Those are SMD codes on the components, it isn't always possible to find what the actual component is. You can make a more educated guess by: 1) using a multimeter in diode mode to check for diode junctions in the transistors. 2) Examine the circuit around the transistor to see if it matches a commonly used circuit for a BJT or MOSFET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parts in the top photo are likely Nexperia [PMV45EN2](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/916/PMV45EN2-1600002.pdf) N-channel MOSFETs.

The  parts in the bottom photo are likely Nexperia [BC849](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BC849_BC850.pdf) BJTs from the 'C' beta bin.